# How to multiply unknown number of php array values by each other?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a database output loop.

I need to multiply values in `$total`, assign the result to another variable and output it. How should I do this?

`$quantity` comes from `$_POST`.

```
$items = implode(",",array_keys($_POST));

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM
    items
WHERE
    item_id IN (' . $items . ')';

$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));

echo ' 

<table id="items">
<tr class="head">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Subtotal</td>
</tr>

';
$total = array ();  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<tr class="targetfields">';
echo '<td>' . $row['item_name'] . '</td>

<td>' . $row['item_cost'];
//Getting item id
foreach ($_POST as $itemid=>$quantity)
{
//Displayin' quantity
if ($itemid == $row['item_id']){
    echo '</td><td><input name="' . $row['item_id'] . '" class="input-small" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text" value="';
    echo "{$quantity}";
    echo '" readonly></td>
    <td>'; $sum = ($row['item_cost'] * $quantity); echo $sum;
    echo '</td>';

    $total.= $sum;

}


}
        echo '</tr>';
}

?>  <tr>
<td class="sum" colspan="4">    Total: 
<?php 



?> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show your full code with `$quantity` initialization

Comment: so you want multiplication of `$row['item_cost'] * $quantity` and store its calculation in array for each iteration?

Comment: @Yogesh Yes, exactly. I'm taking the array to store calculations of every iteration, then myltiplying every calculation by each other and output it.

Comment: Then `Prashant's` answer is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$total .= $sum;` this will not work change it to : `$total[] = $sum;`
2. To get the product all elements of array `$total` use : after while loop `array_product`

ie :

```
$items = implode(",",array_keys($_POST));

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM
    items
WHERE
    item_id IN (' . $items . ')';

$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$total = array ();  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$sum = ($row['item_cost'] * $quantity); echo $sum;      
$total[] = $sum;

}

echo array_product($total);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be

```
$sum = 1; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sum = $row['item_cost'] * $sum; 
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: What about the `$quantity` ?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra there is no need for `quantity`.Because the multiplication will be of the rows selected from query. And main thing `$quantity` is never initialised here so it will create error here.

Comment: Wouldn't $sum be $row['item_cost'] * 1 at each row and echo $sum would only show the last calculation?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld In each iteration it will assign the multiplication to `$sum` and in next iteration it will be used for multiplication.

Comment: Aha ok thanks! Sometimes the most basic things are not obvious enough :-)